# How to remove certain feed from my dashboard in WP admin

Tags: admin, rss, feed

E.g. From some plugin I have, a RSS feed called WP marketing feed is generated. How to remove just this one feed from my WP admin? I want others to remain as they are.

Comment: Try searching a field for that feed in the screen options on the top right corner of the dashboard. If it's checked, remove the check mark and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a column in page, post or custom field, this plugin should be able to do that for you, you can choose the columns that are show in wp-admin and remove the ones you dont want: http://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

But if you mean the RSS feed appears in the left hand menu, then you could remove it with this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

Hope this helps,
Spanglish Webs